# Can we create partitions in a kafka topic programmatically in python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am using kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 and I want to send data from various data sources to various partitions in a topic creating partitions programatically as the data arrives. Can kafka do this? If so, how?

Comment: Fixed spelling, capitalization, and phrasing, and added clear statement of question in body.

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761598/is-it-possible-to-create-a-kafka-topic-with-dynamic-partition-count